# Процесс не завершается

Tags: python

По идее, код должен работать так: считываются имена всех открытых программ, и, если название программы есть в бан-листе, программа должна закрываться, но ничего не происходит...
вот код:

```
while True:

    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        name = proc.name()
        banlist = ["calc.exe"]
        

        if name in banlist:
            print(name)
            os.system("taskkill /f /im  {name}")

        else:
            sleep(3)
```

PS: У меня Windows 10

Comment: Попробуйте напечатать все `name` для начала

Comment: зачем? оно просто отправит все активные процессы

Comment: Чтобы посмотреть - есть там вообще `calc.exe`, может он как-то по-другому пишется или его там нет. Отладочная печать всегда полезна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я подозреваю, что Вы хотели вставить вместо `{name}` название программы, однако в таком варианте будет выполнен скрипт `taskkill /f /im {name}` без указания на какой-либор файл.

Я предлагаю воспользоваться [f-строками](https://python-scripts.com/f-strings), т.е. в данном случае просто добавить `f` перед начальными кавычками строки, вот так:

```py
os.system(f"taskkill /f /im  {name}")
```

Comment: ой, изначально там был не рабочий код, и я переписал его на этот, и забыл f